# The argument of complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis

Let w be a given real number and determine the argument:

$$\frac{1}{(1+2iw)^{2}}$$

This is how far I came:

$$\frac{(1-2iw)^{2}}{(1+2iw)^2(1-2iw))^2} = \frac{(1-2w^{2}) - 4iw}{(1+4w^{2})^{2}} = \arctan \left ( \frac{- 4w}{1-4w^{2} } \right ) $$

And here I am stuck...

Comment: $(1-2iw)^2 = (1-4w^2) - 4iw$, so it would be $$\arctan \frac{-4w}{1-4w^2},$$ which is simpler. But you need to be careful to check in which quadrant the number lies.

Comment: Yes it would depend on w in our case I think? if $$ w > (1/2)^{1/2}$$
But still, I am stuck there :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: How is the argument of $(1+2i w)^{-2}$ related to that of $1+2i w$? How would you interpret the argument of the latter geometrically?

Comment: I would say it is in the first quadrant and it should be arctan 2... ohhh now I got it. 
You mean if $$ (1 + 2i)^{-2} = -2 * arg((1+2i)) $$
So this gives us: $$-2 arctan 2w$$ tada! Or nada?

Comment: I guess you have mistyped and meant $(1+2iw)^{-2}$ and $1+2iw$ in the first line. Otherwise, I could make no sense of the answer.

Comment: Oof, quite so. Will fix @DanielFischer

Comment: @Ara: Not quite. As Daniel pointed out, I typo-ed that pretty badly. But you've got the right idea: keeping in mind that the angle should lie in $(-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, it's just $\arg[(1+2i w)^{-2}]=-2\arg(1+2 i w)$. So all you need to do is work out the latter, and you can figure that out geometrically (draw the point in the complex plane).